# What are the easiest to get/make LN2 superconductors?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, superconductivity

I am starting to build multistage Peltier cooler at the moment, and it should be able to reach -100C at least (but if I fail I can always get boring [LN2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_nitrogen)).

Doing some experiments with superconductors would be great, but where can I get superconductor samples or which one is easier to make on my own (have access to all chemicals & lab).

Especially awesome would be to be able to make thin superconductor film.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Even if your Peltier cooling device can get to -100C, there are no known superconductors that will work at that high a temperature. The current record is about -150C I'm afraid

Comment: Also, should that be 'thin superconductor film'?

Comment: @Brendan, you right about typo. Well, I can always cool first stage of my peltier thing with dry ice or LN2, or just go for bare LN2. The main problem is finding/obtaining superconductor.

Comment: Getting access to a cuprate HTSC superconductor really depends on what you intend to study.  If you intend to do some serious scientific study, then you may be able to contact someone that does synthesis at at university, or they may even have spare material from a synthesis batch that they aren't using.  If you want a recipe to make superconductors, these are readily available in the literature, though they frequently require tools that might not be in the standard chemistry labs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The owner of superconductors.org has [a list of places to find HTSC superconductors, kits, and instructions.](http://www.superconductors.org/Play.htm)

You can also review the literature for recipes.  HTSC producers usually publish successful and repeatable recipes in refereed journals, and some components are available commercially.

Answer (score 1):

Making large, good, high-Tc superconductor crystals is usually difficult. Also thin films are normally grown in specialised setups (i.e. Pulsed laser deposition, molecular beam epitaxy labs. etc.)

However blocks of YtBaCuO are available commercially. This transition at around 90K which is above the 77K boiling point of liquid nitrogen.