# Superconductors and electrical fields

Tags: electricity, fluid-dynamics, superconductivity

I have been looking around to figure out how superconductors are made. What ways are there to create a superconductor that don't involve a coolant like liquid nitrogen? Is it possible to cause a material to become a superconductor by running electric current through it? How practical is it to create a superconductor using any of these methods?

Comment: Hi Rudy, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Some parts of your question were quite vague and are not particularly what we like to see on this site, but in general you have a good question so I removed the vague parts and rephrased the rest to try to make it more clear. You can edit your question further if you feel it's necessary.

Comment: thank you i have been doing programing here so sorry about the vagueness probably should have reread it. Thank you for the edits.

Comment: I had a stange idea that if a metal was a strong superconductor then i could use it to reduce friction in water. By using the forces in the superconductivity to move the polar molecules away from a Remote underwater vehicle im trying to make.

Comment: what the heck can i report someone for going to each question i asked and downvoting then, because every question on every site i have asked has gotten down voted with in 5 minutes of each other.

Comment: The Stack Exchange system automatically reverses runs of apparent "revenge downvoting". If the downvotes don't disappear within 36 hours, send an email to team@stackexchange.com identifying the questions that are still downvoted.

Comment: yah i come on here to put something on a meta and it said i had no where near the reputation to do that i then find out every single question i had was downvoted at the exact same hour. including ones that had recieved little to no attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way is to figure out some tricky atom structure which will work at higher temperatures. Check out existing examples:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSCCO

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-temperature_superconductivity#Examples

You (probably) can't make a superconductor by passing current through non-superconductor, but I don't say it's impossible. From the IT side, if one would be able to create precise model for superconductivity in any atom structure and then bruteforce different structures, then it might be possible to invent something new. But this is insanely large piece of work.

Comment: yah my budget is (and patience) 0. as much as that would be a cool project i got money for scuba diving but not to make expensive models. Is it costly to make superconductive materials with liquid nitrogen?

Comment: If you already have a 1000C oven, you can fit in some 100$. Also, you may buy superconductor samples itself.

Comment: Check out my question : http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12025/what-are-the-easiest-to-get-make-ln2-superconductors